# scala regex to populate data with sign

Tags: scala

````
val strList = List("point+100", "point-100")
val pattern = """\w+""".r
println(strList.map(pattern.findAllIn(_).toList))```
````

Actual output : List(List(point, 100), List(point, 100))
Expected output : List(List(point, +100), List(point, -100))

Would like to know why it's not giving expected output and how can I achieve it..?

Comment: Adding one more scenario to strList => "point100"
expected o/p: List(List(point, +100), List(point, -100), List(point, 100))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get expected output because *+/-* are not word characters `\w`, you could split right before `+/-` with *look ahead* (?=) syntax in your case:

```
strList.map(_.split("(?=[+-])"))
// res84: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(point, +100), Array(point, -100))
```

Or you can add the `+/-` sign in front of `\w+` and make it optional in which way it will extract a word along with the `+/-` sign in front of it if it exists:

```
val pattern = """[+-]?\w+""".r
// pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [+-]?\w+

println(strList.map(pattern.findAllIn(_).toList))
// List(List(point, +100), List(point, -100))
```

Even better, you may add `+-` only in front of digits:

```
val strList = List("point+100", "point-100", "point100")

val pattern = """[a-zA-Z]+|[+-]?\d+""".r
// pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-zA-Z]+|[+-]?\d+

println(strList.map(pattern.findAllIn(_).toList))
// List(List(point, +100), List(point, -100), List(point, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom. My usecase have much more complex scenarios.
Let's add one more case to strList = "point100", where expected output to be List(List(point, +100), List(point, -100), List(point, 100))

Comment: Try the last method. Not sure what more complex situation you have. But if your strings are of pattern *letters* + *digits* with optional +/- sign, this should work.